# Blender Animation - X-flipped pose don't work

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode

When I try to paste the x flipped pose , the pose is completely distorted. I do an auto-names and reroll but it change nothing. [image: when I x flipped the pose]

Comment: Hello, probably because some bones are not correctly orientate, but maybe share your file?

Comment: Hello, here the file (its wetransfer) https://we.tl/t-uQZyrPeXC7

Comment: Your opposite bones need to have the suffixe _R or .R, but for example here you have bones that are named shin.L.IK or upper_arm.L.IK, you need to change that to shin.IK.L for example, see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: ok thanks I try it

Comment: it's really much better thanks !

Comment: is it much better or has it fixed your problems?

Comment: ça a réglé le problème, merci beaucoup !

Comment: tu es le bienvenu   ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your opposite bones need to have the suffixe *_R* or *.R*, but here you have bones that are named *shin.L.IK* (or *upper_arm.L.IK*), you need to change that to *shin.IK.L* for example.